# How to show a same html element's change in a loop with js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loops, element

I want to show a progress by changing an element's text like below:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    $('#progressing > #num').html(i + '/' + 1000);

    // do other things
    ...
}
```

But it seems that explorer has mingle the change on the element, i can only see the last loop's result.

i have tried to use setInterval, and it works well:

```
    setInterval(function(self) {
            $('#progressing > #num').html(self.progress + '/' + 1000);
            self.progress += 1;
    }, 1, this);
```

But i think it's not cool. May i ask for a elegant way to show element change  immediately, just like flush function in IO, or some other way?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what's not 'cool' about it. If it's meant to measure an actual download progress, this isn't the way to do it. But for a general purpose counter, it works fine. Note you can reduce the code to one line if you like

```
let progress=0, max=1000, s=setInterval(()=>(progress++ > max-1 ? clearInterval(this) : $('#el').html(progress + '/' + max)),10);
```

```js
let progress=0, max=1000, s=setInterval(()=>(progress++ > max-1 ? clearInterval(this) : $('#el').html(progress + '/' + max)),10);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='el'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the for loop is running to fast, so the event will raise on the final result only. For debugging, i think you will need to log console or use interval instead of for loop.

```
var counter = 0;
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
    if(counter === 100){ //loop 100 times
        //stop loop (finished loop)
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }else{
        counter ++;
        $('#progressing > #num').html(self.progress + '/' + 1000);
        //do your other code here
    }
}, 2000); //each time process 2 seconds
```